# Parse a string of the following format into a datetime value

Tags: r, parsing, rstudio

I have a column df$datetime which is actually a string. It has the following format:
`2019-08-12T01:04:24Z`.

My question is: How can I turn this column from a string into a normal datetime column?

The desired output is the datetime column of the following format:
`2019-08-12 01:04:24`, not a string column.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

Or

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(str1)
```

Or with `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anytime(str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '2019-08-12T01:04:24Z'
```